# Android MediaPlayer to play audio file from web, but it cannot play .ape, .flac large size audio?

Tags: android

I use android mediaplayer to play audio file from web, it can play .mp3 audio, but it cannot play .ape, .flac, .wma audio.

I tried my app in differenet android device(Android 6.0+), only one device could play all audio format, i found that .ape, .flac files were very large. These files are more than 20m, so i tried to test a small .flac audio, all devices could play it.

```
    private void prepareMusic(String uriString) throws IOException {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(uriString));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        //mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        //mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        //@Override
        //public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //    Log.i(TAG, "prepared...");
        //    playMusic();
        // }
        //});
    }
```

```
    private class MusicAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Object, Object> {
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            String uri = HttpUtil.MUSIC_URL + Util.encodeURL(strings[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, uri);
            prepareMusic(uri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            playMusic();
        }
    }
```

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1313)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

Comment: Those formats need CODECs that are not included in Android. In other words: the App should support this codec.